# Invoke-WebRequest freezes / hangs

Tags: powershell, freeze, invoke-webrequest

Why does the cmdlet "Invoke-WebRequest" freezes / hangs on certains URLs? Any workaround possible? I want to access the "span" objects for a given webpage and this cmdlet would be very useful if it didn't hang like that.

For example, this hangs:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://cloud.google.com/chrome-enterprise/browser/download/"
```

This doesn't :

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.microsoft.com/fr-ca/"
```

-UseBasicParsing makes it run but I want to use the functionality of what Invoke-WebRequest returns without basic parsing because with basic parsing, the span field i'm trying to extract is not populated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to still be a bug in powershell

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2867

A possible work around is to convert the item into parsed HTML manually

```
Function ConvertTo-NormalHTML {
    param([Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]$HTML)

    $NormalHTML = New-Object -Com "HTMLFile"
    $NormalHTML.IHTMLDocument2_write($HTML.RawContent)
    return $NormalHTML
}

$Content = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://cloud.google.com/chrome-enterprise/browser/download" -UseBasicParsing ).Content

$ParsedHTML = ConvertTo-NormalHTML -HTML $Content

$ParsedHTML
```

Comment: Good one there, much appreciated.

Comment: It should be "$Content = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://cloud.google.com/chrome-enterprise/browser/download" -UseBasicParsing )" though. Without the ".content" in the end.

Comment: @JustAGuy, adding -UseBasicParsing worked just great and prevents the hangups.

Comment: -UseBasicParsing has not solved this issue for me

Comment: No error it just hangs and never returns.   I identified the error - Akamai was tarpitting the requests.   Is there a way to trap this error?

Comment: @JamesMoore Not that I know of....how did you figure out that was the issue?

Comment: I am running this through a scriptblock hitting a remote server with no proxy. My request works for few severs, but one in particular hangs just like you discuss here, even with the -UseBasicParsing option. If I stop IIS on the server, I get a response that it could not reach the host. So something is happening, I just cannot tell exactly what.